# Does a 64-bit application run with a 32-bit Oracle client?

Tags: oracle, delphi

I have a 32-bit application written in Delphi and recently I've migrated that to 64 bits.

Now I'm having trouble connecting to an Oracle database.

My Oracle client installation is a 32-bit application. Do I need to have a 64-bit Oracle client or is there some DLL or something that I'm missing?

Comment: You need a 64-bit client.

Comment: No, your client must match the application using it, so you need a 64-bit client to use with a 64-bit application.

Comment: In case you need both, the 32-bit and the 64-bit Oracle client, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Thanks Guys. @KenWhite Post you comment as an answer and I will Accept

Comment: There is no way for me to change only oci.dll to 64 bits version without have to install the whole oracle client 64 bits?